# Multiple streams over a single TCP connection in python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-sockets

I am in the process of making a desktop app, and I need to handle client connections for things like authentication, uploading files, downloading files, reciving notifications, etc.

I know it is possible to achieve this with sockets/asyncio streams by opening a new one for every request, but it has the downgrade of needing to intialize multiple TLS connections, etc...

I am searching for a more modern-abstract solution, something like http 2 multiplexing - using the same TCP connection with multiple streams. But I can't find a standard way to do it in python without making it myself over asyncio or something...

I found a few projects on GitHub trying to solve it,e.g https://github.com/frankurcrazy/tcpchan

But they don't seem mature enough.

I know that higher services like gRPC can do it for me, but I can't use them in this project.

Comment: There isn't a standard way – you'll have to roll up your sleeves and write your own, I'm pretty sure. Also, surely you already have some sort of packetizing/framing in your TCP connection, right..? ;)

Comment: This is a strange question. You name three protocols already but they all don't seem to fit you without any good explanation. So, what are your requirements then?

Comment: Okay, that's what I expected to hear. I do have a protocol for sending simple messages, but for the uploading/downloading files I know protocols like http/ftp use a dedicated connection/stream and don't split it to pieces, so I'm not sure how to handle that. I could, of course, send and recv files in pieces but wouldn't it be less efficient? (Unless I'll implement it to be as effective as http2 multiplexing...) @AKX

Comment: My teacher wants us to deal with streams, nothing higher than that...  @KlausD.

Comment: Less efficient than what? Anyway, there's no such thing as a "stream" when it comes down to the wire anyway; for HTTP and FTP, things are [split into TCP segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) in any case...

Comment: Than opening a new TCP connection for sending a file's bytes in a continuous stream (without spliting it)... HTTP and FTP do that, but since HTTP 2.0 http can handle multiple streams of data over a single TCP/TLS connection which cancels the overhead of opening new TCP streams, although a new overhead of handling those streams is created... @AKX

Comment: Well, I suppose the efficiency tradeoff is up to you to make - do you want the overhead of making multiple connections (with TCP and TLS handshakes and all that), or the overhead of muxing things into a single connection...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.